# How to redirect a non-www URL to a www URL on a Domino server?

Tags: ssl, lotus-domino

There are answers on how to do this with an Apache web server, but is there a way to redirect a non-www url to a Domino web server so that it always uses www?   For example redirecting acme.com to use www.acme.com.   This is needed because browsers will report an SSL certificate error if the exact host name does not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your Domino server to "Load Internet configurations from Server\Internet Sites documents", and create a web site document for acme.com with a Redirection rule that redirects to www.acme.com:

[image]

Comment: Thanks,  didn't know you could redirect any URL using /*   (would've figured that would create some type of loop.)